# Google App Engine + Google Apps + Custom Domain + SSL/SNI

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

I'm trying to enable connection throught SSL to an AppEngine-application for a custom domain. After reading documentation on cloud.google.com, appengine.google.com and admin.google.com, it's only clear that these three projects have three different teams with different mindsets and information. All three of these documentations state three different and invalid methods, as well as different pricings. I'm at the point where I've (in Google Apps) 'enabled' SSL form my custom domain for my Google App Engine-app, and accepted this IN AppEngine. In Google Apps, it now says 'add 5 SNI slots for $9', with a greyed out button, where it on top says in red text something translated to "Billed to App Engine: **ID**. The applications should have good reputation and billing enabled". Our App Engine has billing enabled, and have been billing for a couple of months. This is the only place I've read that we need 'Good reputation'. We're still in development, how should we gain *reputation*?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, the 'add 5 SNI slots for $9' is inaccurate, and Google needs to fix that.  You get 5 slots for free.  I have confirmed with Google that you should still select the 'add 5 SNI slots for $9' option, then proceed, and you will not be billed.  There is no other way that I could find to get the 5 slots for free.   We proceeded with that option, and have not been billed.  They need to fix that page.

Comment: Yes, I found out this as well, sadly this is not an answer to my actual question. I am not able to click 'add 5 SNI slots for $9', the button is greyed out, disabled. Above it, with red text, it says what I typed in the question, about 'reputation'. I have enabled billing for Google App Engine AND Google Apps. I can not find any information on this anywhere.